# Retrofit - Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, okhttp

I have been trying to make request to a server using Retrofit and its been giving me this error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x60cc49f8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

This code has always worked until now, i didn't touch anything nor change anything, and I am wondering what happened to the Library.

See below:

```
String BASE_URL = "https://api.example.com";

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        PayInterface service = retrofit.create(PayInterface.class);

        Call<PaymentData> call = service.getPost();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PaymentData>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<PaymentData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                // Get result Repo from response.body()
                // response.isSuccess() is true if the response code is 2xx

                int statusCode = response.code();
                if (response.isSuccess()) {

                    PaymentData post = response.body();
                    System.out.println("my post: "+post.getMessage());

                } else {
                    // handle request errors yourself
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("failed: "+t);
            }
        });
```

My Interface:

```
public interface PayInterface {

    @Headers({
            "Key1: xxx",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "User-Agent: My-App-Name"
    })
    @POST("/path/another-path")
    Call<PaymentData>
    getPost();

}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'

}
```

Please, is there anything am missing?

Comment: What SSL/TLS protocols does your host server support? Have you recently updated your android OS version? Is your device's SSL provider library up to date?https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html Is there a reason why you cannot be operating on okhttp 3.3?